WPF C# GroupBox Control
I currently need to get the content information within the textbox(s) with a groupbox, these textbox(s) have same first five characters. I'm pretty new at WPF C# and have read a few posts about the need to dig down within the layer(s) using the grid as control within the groupbox but just wanting a cleaner picture or cleaner code to do this action.
Structure:

GroupBox

Grid

Grid

StackPanel

TextBox









In window forms I used this but wanting to do the same thing using WPF:
for (int i = 0; i < (int)NudLengtht; i++)
{
    if (!Byte.TryParse(((TextBox)GrpMessage.Controls.Find("TG_TxtData" + i.ToString(), true)[0]).Text, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out datat[i]))
        AddMessage(LstStatus, "Error converting data to send:" + ((TextBox)GrpMessage.Controls.Find("TG_TxtData" + i.ToString(), true)[0]).Text);
}


The main approach in WPF is to follow the MVVM pattern. Read about it first, once you do that, you'll realize how much headache you had before.

Digging down view elements is not what a developer is supposed to do. Bind the TextBox with a property of view model and work with that property.

In WPF when you name a XAML element you can reference it from the partial C# class using that name like a field (WPF does in fact generates private fields for named elements for that purpose). That's the most simple solution. A slightly more advanced solution is to use data binding (recommended). For example if the TextBox is a child of MainWindow then you can create a dependency property in the MainWindow class and bind the TextBox.Text property to it.

You don't have to use MVVM especially if your application is very small. But it won't hurt for sure.

You could use the VisualTreeHelper class and recursive method to enumerate all children of a specific type:
IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxesInGroupBox = FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(theGroupBox);
...
private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj == null)
        yield return (T)Enumerable.Empty<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        if (child == null)
            continue;
        if (child is T t)
            yield return t;
        foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            yield return childOfChild;
    }
}

Sample XAML markup:
<GroupBox x:Name="theGroupBox">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="a" />
                <TextBox Text="b" />
                <TextBox Text="c" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>

